# How to create a custom Kotlin Inspection for Intellij Idea programmatically

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin for Intellij Idea which provides additional inspections for Kotlin language. Following the example from official documentation for creating inspections for Java, I ended up with following code, which is not working.

Here is the link to a repository with this project: https://bitbucket.org/magycbytes/kotlin-inspections/src/master/

Links to example I followed:

- docummentation page: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/code_inspections.html
- example project: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/master/code_samples/comparing_references_inspection

This is the provider for inspections.

```
package com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections;

import com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionToolProvider;
import com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleInspection;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class ExampleProvider implements InspectionToolProvider {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Class[] getInspectionClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ExampleInspection.class};
    }
}
```

This is the actual inspection subclass. For the sake of shortness it's doing nothing, but should be loaded. Note: I changed the superclass to **AbstractKotlinInspection**

```
package com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.inspections.AbstractKotlinInspection;

public class ExampleInspection extends AbstractKotlinInspection {
    @Nls
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Kotlin Test";
    }
}
```

My `buid.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.2'
}

group 'com.magicbytes'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

intellij {
    version '2018.1.4'
    plugins 'kotlin'
}
```

Mine `plugin.xml` looks like this:

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections</id>
    <name>Plugin display name here</name>
    <description></description>

    <depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- Add your extensions here -->
        <inspectionToolProvider implementation="com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleProvider"/>
    </extensions>

    <actions>
    </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

I did all the linking with *plugin.xml* file. But when I'm running I'm getting exception in testing IDE. Appreciate any insight. NOTE: I'm using `runIde` to debug the plugin.

Exception which I'm getting..

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getExtension(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensions(ExtensionPointImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.getExtensions(ExtensionPointName.java:50)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolRegistrar.ensureInitialized(InspectionToolRegistrar.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolRegistrar.createTools(InspectionToolRegistrar.java:127)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.processOptions(InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.java:34)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader.preload(SearchableOptionPreloader.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$0(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$initComponent$1(Preloader.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.loadImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentImplementation(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:73)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.loadImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:158)
    ... 23 more
Caused by:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.loadImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:161)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentImplementation(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getExtension(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensions(ExtensionPointImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.getExtensions(ExtensionPointName.java:50)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolRegistrar.ensureInitialized(InspectionToolRegistrar.java:54)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolRegistrar.createTools(InspectionToolRegistrar.java:127)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.processOptions(InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.java:34)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader.preload(SearchableOptionPreloader.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$0(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$initComponent$1(Preloader.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProvider PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections, 1.0-SNAPSHOT] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6f989177
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.loadImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:158)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: What is exactly the exception that you get?

Comment: Sorry for not adding it. Please check updated question.

Comment: What is your `plugin.xml` and how exactly do you run the testing IDE?  What exact tutorial have you followed/how did you create the project? Do you use the `IDEA` target generated in the plugin project for running? The exception looks like a misconfiguration.

Comment: Would you mind providing _full_ code of your classes? Including imports, package names, etc.

Comment: Understood. I was trying to minimise the content in question. Now I added more details. Please find attached `plugin.xml` file and `build.gradle` as well. For testing the plugin I'm running `runIde` Gradle task. In addition I updated Java classes to include imports and packages.

Comment: I added a link to repository where the whole project code resides. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @VadimSalajan Wild guess: what if you rename `src/main/src/com/...` to `src/main/java/com/...`?

Comment: @VadimSalajan, what kotlin library you include to get access to `AbstractKotlinInspection`?

Comment: In mine *build.gradle* file I added `plugins 'kotlin'` which added the Kotlin plugin and this way I can get access to Kotlin PSI classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I've imported your GitHub repo and built it locally I've found out that `./build/libs/kotlin.inspections-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` includes `META-INF` only, but no classes. I suspect it's because your source code is located under `./src/main/src`, not `./src/main/java` as it's typical for Gradle projects, so it simply assumes you have no code at all.

After renaming that inner `src` directory into `java` the error changed to

```
class com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleInspection: group display name should be overridden or configured via XML class com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleInspection
java.lang.Throwable: class com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleInspection: group display name should be overridden or configured via XML class com.magicbytes.kotlin.inspections.ExampleInspection
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:123)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionProfileEntry.getGroupDisplayName(InspectionProfileEntry.java:230)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionProfileEntry.getGroupPath(InspectionProfileEntry.java:239)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionToolWrapper.getGroupPath(InspectionToolWrapper.java:161)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.processOptions(InspectionSearchableOptionContributor.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader.preload(SearchableOptionPreloader.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$null$0(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$initComponent$1(Preloader.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

which is much better and looks like a separate problem with your code violating some contract.

Comment: Indeed you are right. This is the solution, wrong names of root folder name. The crash you see right now it's because of not overriding a method to provider group display name. If I'm fixing this warning, no more crashes. Thank you very much for your help!!!